# Powershell check windows optional features disabled

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to check via powershell if some windows 10 optional features are disabled and add all components if any are missing. The $required_IIS_results foreach loop may not be the most efficient method. Here's what I have so far:

```
$required_IIS_features = @(
    # Windows 10 IIS Features
    "IIS-WebServerRole",
    "IIS-WebServer",
    "IIS-WebServerManagementTools",
    "IIS-ManagementConsole",
    "IIS-CommonHttpFeatures",
    "IIS-CGI",
    "IIS-HttpRedirect",
    "IIS-IPSecurity"
    )

Function Confirm-IISPrerequisites {
    #Check to see if IIS components are installed
    Write-Host "## Determining if all necessary IIS components have been installed" -ForegroundColor Green
    $required_IIS_results = ForEach ($feature in $required_IIS_features) {Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $feature | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Disabled"}}

    If($required_IIS_results){
        Write-Host "Installing Required IIS and CGI module" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServer
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerManagementTools
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CGI
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpRedirect
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-IPSecurity
    } Else {
        Write-Host "## All of the Necessary IIS Role Services have been installed" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
#execute function
Confirm-IISPrerequisites
```

Answer (score 2):

a way to avoid foreach:

```
$required_IIS_features = @(
    # Windows 10 IIS Features
    "IIS-WebServerRole",
    "IIS-WebServer",
    "IIS-WebServerManagementTools",
    "IIS-ManagementConsole",
    "IIS-CommonHttpFeatures",
    "IIS-CGI",
    "IIS-HttpRedirect",
    "IIS-IPSecurity"
)
$required_IIS_results = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName IIS* -Online | Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -in $required_IIS_features -and $_.state -eq "Disabled"}
```

and then instead of trying to enable everything, enable only the features that were missing:

```
If ($required_IIS_results)
{
    foreach ($MissingFeature in $required_IIS_results)
    {
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $MissingFeature
    }
}
```

Comment: from `$required_IIS_results = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName IIS* -Online | Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -in $required_IIS_features -and $_.state -eq "Disabled"}`

Comment: Overlooked that, sorry.

Comment: no problem, btw on my machine it runs around 3x faster compared to invoking get-windowsOptionalFeature for each feature individually, although in absolute numbers it is only around ~2 sec difference

Comment: @AurimasN.- Thanks! I'm still pretty new at coding.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check every req. feature and install immediately

```
Function Confirm-IISPrerequisites {
    #Check to see if IIS components are installed
    Write-Host "## Determining if all necessary IIS components have been installed" -ForegroundColor Green
    ForEach ($feature in $required_IIS_features) {
        IF ((Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $feature).State -eq "Disabled"){
           Write-Host "$($feature) missing - installing" -ForegroundColor Red
           Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $feature
        }
    }
    Write-Host "## All of the Necessary IIS Role Services have been installed" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did at work to search for missing features.

```
$L = (Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where FeatureName -eq Printing- 
Foundation-LPDPrintService)
$M = (Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where FeatureName -eq Printing- 
Foundation-LPRPortMonitor)
if ($L.state -eq "disabled"){enable-windowsoptionalfeature -Online - 
FeatureName "Printing-Foundation-LPDPrintService"}
if ($M.state -eq "disabled"){enable-windowsoptionalfeature -Online - 
FeatureName "Printing-Foundation-LPRPortMonitor"}
```